# What is the advantage of this type inference?

Tags: c#

Using type inference we can write:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
```

but it's not really helping is it? Because the  still requires us to only add ints, so wouldnt it have been easier to just declare the variable of 'int' instead of 'var' ?

Comment: You'd have to declare the variable as `List<int>`, not `int`.

Comment: @nos: Typing isn't the important part - reading is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` doesn't change the output of the compiler - it only makes the code shorter.

The only time that `var` offers anything else is in regards to anonymous types:

```
var foo = new { Bar = 123 };
```

It is important to understand that `var` doesn't mean *dynamic* or *variable* (in the sense that it allows the type of the object to vary) - it just allows you to declare a variable and have the compiler infer the type as if you had declared it.

Comment: ... and allows for anonymous types.

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<MadeUpEmbarrassinglyLongClassName> stupidVariable = new IEnumerable<MadeUpEmbarrassinglyLongClassName>();
```

vs

```
var stupidVariable = new IEnumerable<MadeUpEmbarrassinglyLongClassName>();
```

Which is easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

Its more concise than:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
```

I guess this might be easier to read that using var though, although in this trivial case there's not much in it.

In addition, if the variable is named sensibly, then the what type it is should be fairly clear anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `var` is of unknown type until it is assigned a value. As soon as you assign a value, it becomes the typeof to which it is assigned. This `var` is used in situation when you can't infer at compile time as to what value will be passed to it. The other situation where `var` comes in handy is in LINQ queries. Rather than creating a special class to handle your query returns, you simple assign the result to `var` and it does the rest. You will surely compliment `var` once you start using LINQ

Comment: var is always known at compile time. If you can't infer at compile time you'll get a compile-time error. E.g. `var x = null` isn't allowed to compile, but `var x = (string)null` is.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no advantage. In fact, I believe that code readability suffers a bit (opinion).

The answer to this quesiton boils down to personal preference. The compiler will infer `List<int>()` if `var` is used. Which would you prefer to look at? Which would your peers prefer to look at?

Comment: How does readability suffer?!?  You have the type right there on the line with the variable declaration.  How would typing List<int> twice make the code any more readable?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, readabilty suffers when mixings uses. For example, `var myQuery = from...select List<YourAnonType]>`. In this instance, we need the compiler to infer the type. There are instances (like in the OP), that it's not needed. I would prefer not to have to differentiate mentally when looking at the code. Again, as I stated, this is personal preference. Not everyone's brains work the same :)

Comment: I used to think the way you do, and avoided 'var' like the plague.... then I saw how it improved readability by removing cruft, and now any code that double-declares a variable type looks terrible in my eyes.

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, again, the answer to this question is totally based on preference.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you in my last message. ;)